# MySQL using calculated return values to calculate other values

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have a select Statement with the following:

```
SUM(st.tafPoints/200) as totalFriendReferrals,
SUM(CASE WHEN st.gender = "m" THEN st.tafPoints/200 ELSE 0 END) as maleFriendReferrals,
SUM(CASE WHEN st.gender = "f" THEN st.tafPoints/200 ELSE 0 END) as femaleFriendReferrals
```

I need to calculate the percentage of maleFriendReferrals based on the totalFriendReferrals. These are both derived (ie, not originally in the list of columns) values. So if I try to do something like:

```
CONCAT( (maleFriendReferrals/totalFriendReferrals) *100 , '%') as malePercentReferrals
```

But I get an error:

```
Unknown column 'maleFriendReferrals' in 'field list' – 1 ms
```

Is there a way to do this easily? I need to be able to do this within the query itself, and not have to loop through my results to calculate percentages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the original query to a subquery

```
SELECT CONCAT( (maleFriendReferrals/totalFriendReferrals) *100 , '%') as malePercentReferrals
FROM
  (SELECT
    SUM(st.tafPoints/200) as totalFriendReferrals,
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.gender = "m" THEN st.tafPoints/200 ELSE 0 END) as maleFriendReferrals,
    SUM(CASE WHEN st.gender = "f" THEN st.tafPoints/200 ELSE 0 END) as femaleFriendReferrals
  FROM st) AS subquery
```